# ¿Cómo imprimir la letra del DNI?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

He conseguido crear un programa que me muestre la letra del DNI introduciendo el número en un prompt.
El problema es que ahora no se crear una función para conseguir lo mismo pero en su lugar imprimiendo en pantalla.
Directamente, con el programa que tengo y corrigiendo lo necesario, me muestre un formulario este y luego me imprima lo mismo que me hace con el `alert`.

El código no funciona, ya que he intentado hacer una función y no lo hice bien.
Eliminando esa función y el formulario del html si que funciona.

```js
var resto = 0
var letra = ""

function myLetra (){
  do {
    var numero = document.getElementsByName("numer")
    if (Number(numero) == numero) {
      numero = Number(numero)
      if (numero >= 0 && numero <= 99999999) {
        //CALCULAMOS EL RESTO DE DIVIDIR EL NÚMERO ENTRE 23
        resto = numero % 23
        //SEGÚN SEA EL RESTO ASIGNAMOS UN VALOR A LA VARIABLE LETRA
        switch (resto) {
          case 0:
            letra = "T"
            break
          case 1:
            letra = "R"
            break
          case 2:
            letra = "W"
            break
          case 3:
            letra = "A"
            break
          case 4:
            letra = "G"
            break
          case 5:
            letra = "M"
            break
          case 6:
            letra = "Y"
            break
          case 7:
            letra = "F"
            break
          case 8:
            letra = "P"
            break
          case 9:
            letra = "D"
            break
          case 10:
            letra = "X"
            break
          case 11:
            letra = "B"
            break
          case 12:
            letra = "N"
            break
          case 13:
            letra = "J"
            break
          case 14:
            letra = "Z"
            break
          case 15:
            letra = "S"
            break
          case 16:
            letra = "Q"
            break
          case 17:
            letra = "V"
            break
          case 18:
            letra = "H"
            break
          case 19:
            letra = "L"
            break
          case 20:
            letra = "C"
            break
          case 21:
            letra = "K"
            break
          case 22:
            letra = "E"
            break
          default:
            //SI NO ES UN NÚMERO ENTRE 0 Y 22 MOSTRAMOS UN ERROR
            alert("Numero erroneo")
        }
      }
      //MOSTRAMOS MENSAJE CON EL DNI Y LA LETRA OBTENIDA
      alert("Numero: " + numero + ", Letra: " + letra)
    }
    //SI NO ES UN NÚMERO
    else {
      //SI SE PULSÓ ACEPTAR SIN PONER UN NÚMERO
      if (numero != undefined) {
        alert(numero + " No es un numero")
      }
    }
    //MIENTRAS NO SE PULSE CANCELAR VUELVE ARRIBA
  } while (numero != undefined)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Averigua letra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="numer" placeholder="escribe nº del dni">
    </form>
    <button ondblclick="myLetra">Tu letra</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código, primero para llamar a una función con doble click debes colocar la función con paréntesis `ondblclick="myLetra()"` dentro del botón.

Luego para recuperar el valor del `<input>` usas `document.getElementsByName()`, lo cual no es lo mas adecuado, para este caso es mejor `document.getElementById()` ya que este te regresa un solo elemento.

Luego para recuperar caracteres a partir de números, en lugar de usar `switch` puedes colocar todos los caracteres en un array y luego obtenerlos según el indice:

```
letras=["T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E"];
//por ejemplo esto mostrará la letra en la posición 0, que es T
letras[0];
```

Por ultimo para que se muestre el mensaje en la pagina en lugar de un `alert()` puedes usasr un `<span>` y colocar texto en este con `innerHTML`.

El código funcionando queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
var resto = 0
var letra = ""

function myLetra (){
  //do {
    var numero = document.getElementById("numero").value;
    if (Number(numero) == numero) {
      numero = Number(numero)
      if (numero >= 0 && numero <= 99999999) {
        //CALCULAMOS EL RESTO DE DIVIDIR EL NÚMERO ENTRE 23
        resto = numero % 23
        //SEGÚN SEA EL RESTO ASIGNAMOS UN VALOR A LA VARIABLE LETRA
        letras=["T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E"];
         letra=letras[resto];
      }
      //MOSTRAMOS MENSAJE CON EL DNI Y LA LETRA OBTENIDA
      //alert("Numero: " + numero + ", Letra: " + letra)
      document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML="Numero: " + numero + ", Letra: " + letra;
    }
    //SI NO ES UN NÚMERO
    else {
      //SI SE PULSÓ ACEPTAR SIN PONER UN NÚMERO
      if (numero != undefined) {
        document.getElementById("mostrar").innerHTML="No es un número";
      }
    }
    //MIENTRAS NO SE PULSE CANCELAR VUELVE ARRIBA
  //} while (numero != undefined)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Averigua letra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="numero" placeholder="escribe nº del dni">
    </form>
    <button ondblclick="myLetra()">Tu letra</button><br>
    <span id="mostrar" ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que estabas haciendo mal es llamar una función, sin los () paréntesis, y el otro error es que `document.getElementsByName()` devuelve una lista y no solo un objeto aparte que debes obtener la propiedad `value`, te dejo el ejemplo corregido.

```js
var resto = 0
var letra = ""

function myLetra (){
    var numero = document.getElementsByName("numer")[0].value;
    if (Number(numero) == numero) {
      numero = Number(numero)
      if (numero >= 0 && numero <= 99999999) {
        //CALCULAMOS EL RESTO DE DIVIDIR EL NÚMERO ENTRE 23
        resto = numero % 23
        //SEGÚN SEA EL RESTO ASIGNAMOS UN VALOR A LA VARIABLE LETRA
        switch (resto) {
          case 0:
            letra = "T"
            break
          case 1:
            letra = "R"
            break
          case 2:
            letra = "W"
            break
          case 3:
            letra = "A"
            break
          case 4:
            letra = "G"
            break
          case 5:
            letra = "M"
            break
          case 6:
            letra = "Y"
            break
          case 7:
            letra = "F"
            break
          case 8:
            letra = "P"
            break
          case 9:
            letra = "D"
            break
          case 10:
            letra = "X"
            break
          case 11:
            letra = "B"
            break
          case 12:
            letra = "N"
            break
          case 13:
            letra = "J"
            break
          case 14:
            letra = "Z"
            break
          case 15:
            letra = "S"
            break
          case 16:
            letra = "Q"
            break
          case 17:
            letra = "V"
            break
          case 18:
            letra = "H"
            break
          case 19:
            letra = "L"
            break
          case 20:
            letra = "C"
            break
          case 21:
            letra = "K"
            break
          case 22:
            letra = "E"
            break
          default:
            //SI NO ES UN NÚMERO ENTRE 0 Y 22 MOSTRAMOS UN ERROR
            alert("Numero erroneo")
        }
      }
      //MOSTRAMOS MENSAJE CON EL DNI Y LA LETRA OBTENIDA
      alert("Numero: " + numero + ", Letra: " + letra)
    }
    //SI NO ES UN NÚMERO
    else {
      //SI SE PULSÓ ACEPTAR SIN PONER UN NÚMERO
      if (numero != undefined) {
        alert(numero + " No es un numero")
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Averigua letra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="numer" placeholder="escribe nº del dni">
    </form>
    <button onclick="myLetra()">Tu letra</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver , tu respuesta igualmente valida. Aceptare la del compañero ya que ademas dejo un código mas limpio que el mio. Un saludo